# from models import Event ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Tags: python, django, module

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals  
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
from models import Event
```

I try to build an app with

> python manage.py migrate

from github I get into this problem

> y", line 6, in 
> from models import Event ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

I am not sure how to fix it.No info online this is the repo : https://github.com/alexpnt/django-calendar

Comment: What does your project directory look like? Which import is line 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a qute "old" application to be honest, the last update was 2 years ago.

The new django versions does not support some code in the version in the repo(1.11.19) and we are at the version (3.1.4)

If you are looking to a calendar or a scheduler, i suggest to use [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler)

Plus using by using old versions, you can fall in security issue.

Comment: I try to install this but its get not proper into the screen.

Comment: Anyway how I can fix it to work with current django